# Java - Using Filewriter to save an agenda information on a text file

Tags: java

I want for this class to save info in a blank text file that is already created. It seems to work (no errors nor exceptions) but the file stays blank.

Here is the code:

```
public class AgendaSaver {

    private File AgendaToSave;
    private FileWriter FW;

    public AgendaSaver() {
        this.AgendaToSave = new File("src/agendafullapp/logic/fileHandling/agendaSaverText.txt");
        try {
            FW = new FileWriter(AgendaToSave);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AgendaSaver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void addToFile(theAgenda Agenda) throws IOException {
        Agenda.sortEvents();
        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
        for (Event X : Agenda.getArrayList()) {
            SB.append(X.toString());
            SB.append("\n");
        }

        String finalagenda = SB.toString();
        
        FW.write(finalagenda);

        System.out.println("Saved");
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: close your FW.close(); when the writing is done.

Comment: wow, I feel stupid now ;) I have been looking for the answer for about half an hour already. Thanks! That was it.

Comment: dont feel like that. It can happen.

Comment: @Y.KaanYılmaz Please do not edit in solutions to the Question box. Those belong in the Answer box.

Comment: As an aside, I would strongly encourage you to read up on and start following Java naming conventions.